# Select and display a sentence randomly between two pre-defined sentences

Tags: c++

in the following code I want the compiler to randomly select and display a sentence in c ++ (does this mean random selection among cout?) Do I have to use a special function to do this?  Thank you for your reply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
// Make different numbers
srand(time(NULL));
// generate true number 
// generate random numbers x
int x = rand() % 9 + 1; 
// generate random number y
int y = rand() % 9 + 1;
// x + y = z
int z = x + y;
// generate wrong number 
// generate random number a
int a = rand() % 9 + 1;
// generate random number b
int b = rand() % 9 + 1;
// a + b = c --> c random number
int c = rand() % 9 + 1;
cout << x << "+" << y << "=" << z << endl;
cout << a << "+" << b << "=" << c << endl;

}
```

Comment: [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is what I'd probably use.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are no sentences in your code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No, I mean, by the way, a random choice between the last two couts

Comment: @jesperjuhl That's right, but this is a random choice between two numbers. I want to choose a random random cout between two sentences.

Comment: @RezaShakeri "I want to choose a random random cout between two sentences" - I get that. So, you generate a random number that's either `0` or `1` and if it is `0` you print the first string and if it is `1` you print the second string. Something like `if (number == 0) std::cout << "foo"; else if (number == 1) std::cout << "bar";`

Comment: @jesperjuhl Thank you, I try a good solution, thank you again